# Consume service layer in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an mvc app with a service layer that is exposed through a rest api. I'm used to consuming services using dependancy injection in my controllers, but these services have not been web services.

How would I do this for a service layer exposed as a web service? Would the controller have the web service injected or would I need to make a lightweight wrapper around the web service that the controller can be injected with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were you i would create wrapper around webservice and inject this wrapper. It would give more control.

But before you should discuss necessity of this webservices.

Comment: We are providing an api for external developers to use. I want to consume it too.

Comment: This is what I'm going to do. Thanks.